# Is base method able to use derived base data members?

Tags: c#

Lets assume we have the following code:

```
abstract class Base1 {
    protected int num;
}

class Der1:Base1 {
    protected Color color;
    protected string name;
}

class Der2:Base1 {
    protected DateTime dthen;
}
```

and so on. An array of `base1` type exists and includes many objects created out of classes that are derived from `base1`.

Is it possible to define the `toString()` method in the base class only?
something like:

```
public override string toString()
{
    if (this is Der1)
        return "num = " + this.num + "color = " + this.color.toString() + " name = " this.name;
    if (this is Der2)
        return "num = " + this.num + "dthen = " + this.dthen.toString();
    // and so on ...
}
```

Thank you very much :)

P.S. This is not an homework question. I've just wondered about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to do this is to cast `this` to each derived type.  (And even that will only work if the members are public)

However, you *really* should override the method instead.

Comment: +1 Let the CLR handle the polymorphic dispatch - it's cleaner, faster, and easier to maintain.

Comment: No, `((Der1)this).color` is a compilation error, even inside a `Base1` class.

Comment: Yes, this would be a very bad design to have a class depending on its subclasses.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is impossible unless you change all members' fields access modifier to `public`.

And generally speaking: this is a bad practice. Base classes should not know anything about derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but

- derived classes members should be **public**
- you are missing an explicit **cast**:

  public override string toString()
  {
      if (this is Der1)
          return "num = " + ((Der1)this).num + // etc...

And by the way, **this is very bad**, as you should override ToString in derived classes Der1 and Der2 - that's what polimorphism is for.

Comment: This won't compile - the derived class' fields are not public.

Comment: @SLasks: you are right, thanks. That was not really the point, in any case :)

Answer (score 1):

You should let the derived classes handle how their version of ToString should behave.

Letting the base class depend on all the derived classes makes for a really fragile design.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to avoid is replicating the code in the abstract base class that prints its information in ToString().  You can solve this using a virtual method in the base class like GetExtraString(), which is overridden in descendant classes to only return the extra information you'd like in your base ToString().